# Mod rewrite trouble with ugly GET url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So on my test site (using wamp), I have a GET form asking the user to select a platform (xbl=1 or psn=2) and username. When they submit it, I get this ugly but working url:

(psn example)
testsite.com/test.php?platform=2&username=testusername&submit=

From that, I would like the url to instead be:
testsite.com/psn/testusername

When the user selects xbl as their platform, it gives me this url:
testsite.com/test.php?platform=2&platform=1&username=testusername&submit=

It works but I would like it to return:
testsite.com/xbl/testusername

I have tried the following:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /testsite/test.php?platform=$1&username=$2&submit= [L]

This only works when psn is the selected platform but it shows as testsite.com/2/testusername. I cant figure out how to make it display "psn" when the url contains "test.php?platform=2" and "xbl" when it displays "test.php?platform=2&platform=1" as the double platform is throwing me off

Thanks!

Comment: why create your code with the same parameter that is used twice in your URL and cause issues for you to begin with? Doesn't seem to make since.

Comment: The only way I could get it to pass the PSN value for the toggle switch I have was to set a hidden variable. If I remove line 4 from the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ef8b10b130ed6f50368544806e9beb2 if someone picks psn as their platform, it wont pass in a platform variable and I get an undefined variable in my php code. So when someone picks xbl as their platform, it passes them both in but it ends up setting platform=1 correctly still. I know, very hacky way I guess but it works but youre right, it is making this part difficult

Comment: did you not use any of framework? actually you must modify .htaccess in yout website folder, if you use framework, you can set routes.php or something like that

Comment: no i didnt use a framework. just regular html and php. I just learned php so i didnt quite understand codeigniter when i looked at the docs